# How to install gst-omx-1.9.2 to Ubuntu14.04 (Not Rasberry Pi !)

Tags: gstreamer, openmax

I'm trying to do GPU-supported video encoding/decoding with GStreamer,
because fast UDP streaming of webcam image is required to my project. 
Now I'd like to install gst-omx and OpenMAX from source, but I have a trouble...
Could you help me ?

I've already installed nvidia graphic card driver(3.52.99), cuda-7.5, nvenc(ver.5.0), gstreamer-1.9.2, orc-0.4.26, gst-libav-1.9.2, gst-plugins-base/good/bad/ugly-1.9.2.
gst-*** are installed from source to specify those versions.
Now I think last thing I need is gst-omx-1.9.2, because I'd like to use omxh264(I'm not sure whether omxh264 internally utilizes GPU or not, but I'd like to try this). But I can't.

According to google results,

```
./autogen.sh --with-omx-target=generic
make
sudo make install
```

and everything's gonna be fine. But in my case, make command generates no shared object.
Right after typing make, just move into each directory and just move out the directory without doing anything.

My questions are here.

- What's wrong with the installation ?
- Do I need to add some environment variables ?

Thanks in advance.

Here's a result of autogen.sh.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's a result of make -j 8. Sorry, Japanese is used. It's just saying move into some directory and move out of the directory and so on.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that omx works only for embedded systems like raspberry pi etc where the hw has special chip (just guessing the reason) - on Ubuntu you can try some fake omx (here is mentioned some bellagio..) but this is just for testing. I would recommend using VA-API which really uses GPU for encoding/decoding

Comment: It has option "generic", so I assumed that it supports non-embedded systems :( I'll try to use vaapi ! Thank you ! Can it be used for both of embedded systems and desktop ?

Comment: I think it depends on what graphics driver you are running - check [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/vaapi/#driversback-endsthatimplementva-api) ..

Comment: Thank you. I've checked that and README file in the package. NVIDIA GPU seems to be supported, but README tells that NVIDIA platforms with PureVideo (VDPAU supported) is required.